# Woocommerce CVS Import with Variations?

Tags: woocommerce, import, product-variations

A site we're building is nearly complete and the last thing to do is import all the products (no problem) and importantly, product variations... I looked through the documentation, specifically the Attributes and Product Variations sections, but am still lost on how this should be done.

From the Product Variations section of the documentation, it is my understanding that a separate CSV needs to be imported just for the variations and that I need to use meta:attribute_pa_size, meta:attribute_pa_color, and meta:attribute_pa_style for the column headers.

But then, in the Attributes section, I'm assuming of the main (non-variations) CSV, it says I need to insert these columns: attribute:attribute name, attribute:pa_size, and attribute_data:pa_size

But after playing around with these columns, I'm getting nowhere and can't for the life of me get variations to import.

I have tried manually creating a product, adding variations and getting everything working, then doing a CSV export. Upon entering a new product in exactly the same format into that same CSV and reimporting, the variations still don't show up.

Maybe it has something to do with the "Attributes" menu under "Products"? I had a play in there but am still at a loss.

I know this must be possible, and help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Of course it is possible... it is just a set of database links between tables... nothing which is supposed to be from the next century. But for some reason, product managers turn crazy when developing for commercial software, and tag as "premium" and expect profits from any crappy piece of code. Just a shame.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the method I use, with great success:

1. Buy Mike's CSV Import Suite plugin for Woocommerce (http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-csv-import-suite/)
2. Create attributes and add a product with attributes
3. Export CSV using plugin
4. Use CSV as a template, and fill out the rest of the product info with attributes (split variation with the pipe '|' symbol)
5. Import using plugin

That should sort out your problem

Comment: The exported CSV (for products) doesn't contain the attribute and attribute_data columns, which I think you need to get the available options into the "Attributes" part of the product page? So I have added those manually which creates them correctly.

I then add my options to the meta:attribute part of the variations csv (separated with pipes), if I create 2 variations (for e.g), it is creating 2 variations but they say "Any Colour" and "Any Size" rather than the sizes and colours specified in the CSV.

Comment: Does the variations option work for you when you enter the data manually? Try following this guide: http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/product-variations/

Answer (score 1):

WP All Import is better for importing variable products to WooCommerce because you don't need to have the CSV in a specific format like you do with the import suite from WooThemes.

The WooThemes tool is good if you already have your products inside WooCommerce and want to export them, modify them, and re-import them.

The WP All Import plugin is good if you have an XML or CSV file and just need to get it into WooCommerce without the need to modify the file to get it in some special format.

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions of exporting and using as a template are very good. However if you requires product variations then the export does not, in my experience export what is required.

To achieve this you need a live per variation and the export does not do this.

To answer sootylad's question. you are on the right track. you do need columns:
meta:attribute_pa_colour    meta:attribute_pa_sizes
in the Product Variations CSV but if you want to have different attributes for each variation you need a line in the Product Variations CSV for each difference. EG if you want a different image then you need to add the image slug the "meta:attribute_pa_colour" column.

BE VERY CAREFUL - IT IS CASE SENSITIVE.

Pink is not tha same as pink.

I spent weeks on this. It was driving me round the twist.